# Merging Eloquent result set

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two eloquent outputs

```
allowance   Amount
A           100
B           80
C           120
D           150
```

AND

```
Deductions  Amount
X           50
Y           60
Z           70
```

and json appears as

```
$allowance = [{"allname":"A","allamount":"100"},{"allname":"B","allamount":"80"},{"allname":"C","allamount":"120"},{"allname":"D","allamount":"150"}]
$Deductions = [{"dedname":"X","dedamount":"50"},{"dedname":"Y","dedamount":"60"},{"dedname":"Z","dedamount":"70"}].
```

I want new json to be like

```
$new = [{"allname":"A","allamount":"100","dedname":"X","dedamount":"50"},{"allname":"B","allamount":"80","dedname":"Y","dedamount":"60"},{"allname":"C","allamount":"120","dedname":"Z","dedamount":"70"},{"allname":"D","allamount":"150"}]
```

Kindly guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-merge (and yes Eloquent returns collections when using `get()` (not `first()`)

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have two collections

```
$firstCollection = collect(['one','two']);

$collectionTwo = collect(['three','four']);

$firstCollection->merge($collectionTwo);
```

using `merge()` will merge the two collections.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code you can get what do you want:

```
$a = array(array('allname'   =>'A','allamount'=>'100'),
           array('allname'   =>'B','allamount'=>'200'),
           array('allname'   =>'C','allamount'=>'300'));

$b = array(array('dedname'   =>'X','dedamount'=>'50'),
           array('dedname'   =>'c','dedamount'=>'150'));

$all=array();

for ($i=0; $i < count($a); $i++) { 

   $merged="";   

   if (isset($b[$i])) {

      $merged=array_merge($a[$i],$b[$i]);

   }else{

      $merged=$a[$i];
   }

   $all[]=$merged;
}

echo "<pre>";print_r($all);echo "<br";

header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode($all);
```

output:

> [{"allname":"A","allamount":"100","dedname":"X","dedamount":"50"},{"allname":"B","allamount":"200","dedname":"c","dedamount":"150"},{"allname":"C","allamount":"300"}]

I hope this could help you.